# create-react-app stops after finding 1 low severity vulnerability

Tags: windows, npm, create-react-app

I'm new to React and I can't get `create-react-app` to work. While running `create-react-app`, it freezes upon finding 1 low severity vulnerability while installing packages with `npm`.

- OS: **Windows 8**
- NPM: **v6.14.5**
- Node: **v12.18.0**

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you add logs of what error you are getting?
Try using the LTE Version of Node, Node version 6 is deprecated

Comment: Logging the audit information is the last thing install does, so it's unclear why you think that's a problem. But Node 6 is way out of date now, upgrade to at least 10 per https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

Comment: am using node version 12.18.0 but still getting same error

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning that one of your dependencies may be vulnerable. If you have an *actual problem*, give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

After downloading and installing Node v12.13.1 x86 instead of x64 I managed to create the React app.